# Nested async/await in expressjs fetch

Tags: javascript, express, fetch

My API-middleware code below works so far.
I really want to be sure to not have any blocking calls in my express server. 
So I also made my function which contains the fetch async.

My question is, is that necessary at all? Because actually the first await should already unblock my express server, right?

Here is the code:

```
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()
const asyncMiddleware = require('./utils/asyncMiddleware');

async function fetchCall(URL, bodyJson, wpToken) {      
    try {        
        return await fetch(URL, {
            method: "POST",
            credentials: "same-origin",
            headers:  {
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + wpToken,
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Accept": "application/json"
            },
            body: bodyJson
    });
    } catch (error) {       
        return {status:544, error:error};
    }
}

router.post("/registerVendor", asyncMiddleware(async (req, res, next) => {              
    const response = await fetchCall(myApiUrl, req.body, 1)
    return res
    .status(response.status)
    .send({ data: response});
}));

module.exports = router
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question is, do you have to put your `fetch` in a separate `async` function, the answer is no, you don't *have* to. It may be useful to, but you don't *have* to. As you say, if you directly await the `fetch` promise, that will end the synchronous portion of your `async` route callback.

> My question is, if this function ("fetchCall" in my code example) HAS to be async.

No, it doesn't. It doesn't even have to return a promise, because you can `await` any value. For example, the following logs A, B, C, D, and E in order:

```js
async function foo() {
    console.log("B");
    await 42;
    console.log("D");
}

console.log("A");
foo()
.then(() => {
    console.log("E");
})
.catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
});
console.log("C");
```

In your case, of course, you want to return a promise. :-) This would work:

```
function fetchCall(URL, bodyJson, wpToken) {      
    return fetch(URL, {
        method: "POST",
        credentials: "same-origin",
        headers:  {
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + wpToken,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json"
        },
        body: bodyJson
    })
    .catch(error => ({status:544, error:error}));
}
```

That said, the advantage to `async`/`await` is that it makes writing asynchronous code with the branching and looping constructs we're familiar with from synchronous code possible...

Comment: Thank you. I want to put the fetch in a separate function because I will have other routes using it. My question is, if this function ("fetchCall" in my code example) HAS to be async.

Comment: @flo - It doesn't have to be, no; I've updated the answer.

Comment: Super many thanks! I will accept that as answer. Just another question to understand this promise stuff better: My original fetchCall code has a try catch in comparison to your code. Is my version also ok? Because I just return an object {..} and not a promise. Or is it the same as yours? Still trying to understand promises....

Comment: @flo - Yes, your `async` version is just fine. `async` functions **always** return promises. (You don't have access to the promise they return from within the code of the `async` function.) When you `return` in an `async` function, you're resolving the promise that the function returns. (Similarly, if you `throw`, you're rejecting the promise the function returns.)

Comment: @flo - BTW, my answer had a misleading statement in it when you posted the comment above, so you might want to refresh and read the updated version. Silly mistake on my part. :-)